# Unable to query to search company in linkedinAPI V2

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

My App has SignIn With linkedin and Share on Linkedin both permission assigned.

While retrieving the token, I have used the scope w_member_social as well.

But as per the Linked API documentation: while, I try to use the query to search organization by keywords, I am getting error as -

> "serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET-search /companySearch","status":403

Can you tell me what extra permission is needed here ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the `rw_organization_admin` permission. Actually you have a write-only permission and maybe this is the problem.

Moreover the LinkedIn API states that **"The Company Search endpoint is restricted. This permission is granted to selected developers only."**(as reported [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/company-search?tabs=http))

Comment: I found the below in the documentation as well that  r_organization_social -> Retrieve organizations' posts, comments, and likes. But if i define this in the scope it says error in scope value

Comment: Did you renew the access token with the new permissions? can you also share your api request?